# MYSQL First and last datetime within a day

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table with 3 days of data (about 4000 rows). The 3 sets of data are all from a 30 minutes session. I want to have the start and ending time of each session.

I currently use this SQL, but it's quite slow (even with only 4000 records). The datetime table is indexed, but I think the index is not properly used because of the conversion from datetime to date. 
The tablelayout is fixed, so I cannot change any part of that. The query takes about 20 seconds to run.. (and every day longer and longer). Anyone have some good tips to make it faster?

```
select distinct
date(a.datetime) datetime,
(select max(b.datetime) from bike b where date(b.datetime) = date(a.datetime)),
(select min(c.datetime) from bike c where date(c.datetime) = date(a.datetime))
from bike a
```

[image]

Comment: Alex, are the fields indexed too?

Comment: Yes, The datetime column is indexed.

Comment: Ok, and using JOIN instead of subquerys?

Comment: Well, I considered that but I need to get both the max and min out of it.. so that would make this 3 joins, right?

Comment: Is possible to post the tables?

Comment: ok, did that in my post.

Comment: I think your indices may not be being used because you're using a function of the columns rather than the column itself. For example, even if "b.datetime" is indexed, "date(b.datetime)" is not, resulting in a table scans to match your where clauses.

Comment: Yes, I also assume this is the case.. I could change the datamodel, but I would prefer (for different reasong) not having to.

Comment: No, wasn't suggesting change to datamodel, but reworking query so was able to use indices. Going into meeting now, hope this helps and you get answer. If not will take a look later today for suggestion on the query.

Comment: I just tried with joins, but it doesnt make it much faster.. I guess I still dont use the index correctly.. select max(a.datetime) start,min(a.datetime) end, date(a.datetime) datum from bike a LEFT JOIN bike b on date(a.datetime) = date(b.datetime) group by date(datetime)

Comment: @AlexvanEs, see answer I posted. May not be exactly what you want, but indicates trying to rework the query rather than the data model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but...

Isn't the result returned by the OP query equivalent to the result from this query:

```
  SELECT DATE(a.datetime) AS datetime
       , MAX(a.datetime)  AS max_datetime
       , MIN(a.datetime)  AS min_datetime
    FROM bike a
   GROUP BY DATE(a.datetime)
```

Comment: Thanks.. my mind must have been running in circles last night when i wrote the script with the subqueries! :)

Answer (score 0):

Alex, warning, this in typed "freehand" so may have some syntax problems. But kind of shows what I was trying to convey.

```
select distinct
date(a.datetime) datetime,
(select max(b.datetime) from bike b where b.datetime between date(a.datetime) and (date(a.datetime) + interval 1 day - interval 1 second)),
(select min(c.datetime) from bike c where c.datetime between date(a.datetime) and (date(a.datetime) + interval 1 day - interval 1 second))
from bike a
```

Instead of comparing date(b.datetime), it allows comparing the actual b.datetime against a range calculated form the a.datetime. Hopefully this helps you out and does not make things murkier.

Comment: The change to the predicates in the correlated subqueries should improve performance, by enabling effective use of an index (range scan operation on leading column of `datetime`)... but I don't see any reason those correlated subqueries are needed at all.  Those subqueries are going to be executed for every row in `bike`, and then there's a sort unique operation to remove the "duplicate" rows. There are more efficient approaches to returning the specified result.